# Logging results to the wrong log file

Tags: python, tkinter, logging

I have a little program that does encryption and decryption.
It should log the results in different folders:
Encryption folder for encryption
Decryption folder for decryption

[folders structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPdSf.jpg)

Step 1:
Function that is decrypting the file:

```
def perform_decryption(mainbox, operation_unique_identifier: str, file_path: str):
    operation_code = {'OK': 200, 'BAD REQUEST': 404}
    path_validator = PathValidator(file_path)

    operation_id = operation_code['BAD REQUEST']
    if not path_validator.check_path_existence(file_path):
        log_message = reusable_functions.path_invalid_message(operation_unique_identifier, file_path)
        log_functions.update_file_log(log_message, operation_unique_identifier)
        reusable_functions.update_display_log(mainbox, operation_unique_identifier, operation_id)
        return

    operation_id = operation_code['OK']
    try:
        decryption = Decryption(file_path)
        key = decryption.load_key()
        decryption.decrypt_file(key)

        reusable_functions.update_display_log(mainbox, operation_unique_identifier, operation_id)
        log_decryption_result(operation_unique_identifier, operation_id, decryption.file_key_pair)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Step 2:
Create the log message and pass it to the log_functions module that knows how to handle the date and different details:

```
def log_decryption_result(operation_unique_identifier: str, operation_id: int, file_key_pair: dict[str, str]) -> None:
    log_file_message = (f'\n[{operation_unique_identifier.upper()}: {operation_id}]: '
                        f'\nDecrypted the following file:')
    for file_name, key_path in file_key_pair.items():
        log_file_message += f'\n\t{file_name}'
        log_file_message += '\nKey from the folowing location deleted:'
        log_file_message += f'\n\t{key_path}'

    log_functions.update_file_log(log_file_message, operation_unique_identifier)
```

Step 3:
Give the log_message to the update_file_log function that will provide a name (it's mostly the day of the running and the 'ublog' string -> 13_ublog, 14_ublog and so on)

```
def update_file_log(log_message: str, operation_specific_indentifier: str) -> None:
    log_configurer = LogConfigurer()
    file_name = log_configurer.give_log_name()
    file_path = os.path.join(log_configurer.get_month_folder_path(), operation_specific_indentifier, file_name)
    print(f'This file_path: {file_path}')
    formatting_log(file_path, '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    logging.info(log_message)
```

Step 4:
Format the details and does final polish.

```
def formatting_log(file_path: str, provided_format: str) -> None:
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_path, format=provided_format, level=logging.INFO, datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

**I checked the file_path at this point (at the print). It's the right path:**
This file_path: D:\2xProjects\Python\UtilityBox\resources\results\logs\2023\September\Decryption\13_ublog

**Still, funny enough, it logs everything under this txt file:**
This file_path: D:\2xProjects\Python\UtilityBox\resources\results\logs\2023\September\Encryption\13_ublog

**Decryption txt file is empty, while encryption text file have the following output:**

```
13/09/2023 15:11:11 INFO: 
[ENCRYPTION: 200]: 
Encrypted the following file:
    ewrjuerwjsaluecex
Key saved in the following location:
    D:\2xProjects\Python\UtilityBox\resources\results\keys\ewrjuerwjsaluecex.key
13/09/2023 15:11:17 INFO: 
[DECRYPTION: 200]: 
Decrypted the following file:
    ewrjuerwjsaluecex
Key from the folowing location deleted:
    D:\2xProjects\Python\UtilityBox\resources\results\keys\ewrjuerwjsaluecex.key
```

This is the whole process of my application. After logging.info(log_message) it simply logs the message to the file and that's it. How can it go to the wrong folder since the path is the right one...
The prints that I gave you are from the IDE console, I did in turns an encryption and then a decryption and those are the paths...
If you need any additional info I'll gladly edit the post and provide more.

Thank you!

I tried to track the whole process, even using the debugger... Step by step... Can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Python `logging.basicConfig(**kwargs)` documentation:

> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured, unless the keyword argument force is set to True.

If I understand correctly, you try to re-configure logging using the `basicConfig` function. Easy fix would be to use `force` keyword argument, but a more elegant and straightforward way would be to use `Filter` objects.

Comment: The thing that I miss is how can the information be logged in the Encryption text file (I attached the image) even if the file_path parameter in     
logging.basicConfig(filename=file_path, format=provided_format, level=logging.INFO, datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
is bla bla bla/September/Decryption/13_ublog...
I just don't get it...

Comment: Did you log anything with the bla bla bla?

Comment: No. The thing is that the path is correct. When the flow reaches the logging.basicConfig and passes the file_path as the paramater, that file_path points to the Decryption folder in case of a Decryption operation, still, somehow, the information is logged under the Encryption folder, which is strange...

Comment: That's what I find very strange. The logging.basicConfig will save the string (in my case the log_message) under the file_path that is passed as argument. When I check it, the path is good, still, the Decryption text file remains empty and the so called saving goes to the other text file that should have information only about Encryption operations.

Comment: The `basicConfig` is meant to be called once at the start of the program before any messages have been logged. After logging has started, the basicConfig has no effect anymore (without `force`).

Comment: You should not use `basicConfig`. You should configure different `FileHandler` objects for encryption and decryption. Then opening and closing files is not needed.

Comment: Ohhh... Ok. I thought that basicConfig will always update with the file_path regarding of the point of calling. I used it as an object that is created and destroyed every time a logging operation is performed. That's how I thought that the basicConfig works...

Comment: I think I understood it's usage and purpose wrong

Comment: You are right. The problem is that I tested every function (I have compressing and decompressing also, search etc) one by one each time I finished implementing each one and the logging was correct because of that. Now I see that if I switch between operations then file_path will be the same as the one passed at the initialization...
How should I handle this situation? My approach is even ok or should I change everything at 180 degrees and use something else instead of the logging module?

Comment: It should work if you add parameter `force=True` to the `basicConfig` call.

Comment: Yep, thank you. It works. My problem is that I have a big doubt that my approach is ok. For what you told me and now that I understand the mistake, looks like the way I do this logging is a little bit forced... Not the finest :))